# Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n \log^2(n+1)}$ converges absolutely or conditionally.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

*Problem*

Let $S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n\log^2(n+1)}$.

Determine the series converges absolutely or conditionally.

*Attempt*

$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}( -1)^n a_n$

$a_n$ is monotonically decreasing and it approaches zero when $n$ approaches infinity. So series is convergent .

*Doubt*

How to check for absolute convergence?

Ratio test fails here. Root test is of no use. 
I have attempted comparison tests using the fact that $n>\log(n)$, but no success there also.

Comment: Do you know the integral test?

Answer (score 0):

One option is the [condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) test, which says $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(\log(n+1))^2}$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2^n}{2^n(\log (2^{n+1}))^2}$ does.